# How to Properly Specify the element-type of an Adjustable Vector

Tags: types, common-lisp, adjustable-array

The following is a structure intended to function either as a (lifo) stack or (fifo) queue

```
(defstruct jvector
  (vector (make-array 0 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0) :type (array * (*)))
  (start 0 :type (integer 0 *)))
```

with contents ranging from jvector-start up to the jvector-vector fill-pointer. I’d like to be able to specify the element type of the contents with something like

```
(defun create-jvector (&key (element-type t))
  (make-jvector :vector (make-array 0 :element-type element-type :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)
                :start 0))
```

and push elements with

```
(defun push-jvector (elt jvec)
  (vector-push-extend elt (jvector-vector jvec)))
```

However, the element type in create-jvector is ignored. For example,

```
* (defparameter v (create-jvector :element-type 'integer))
V
* v
#S(JVECTOR :VECTOR #() :START 0)
* (push-jvector 1 v)
0          ;OK result
* v
#S(JVECTOR :VECTOR #(1) :START 0)
* (push-jvector 'a v)
1          ;not OK result
* v
#S(JVECTOR :VECTOR #(1 A) :START 0)
```

Why does pushing ‘a not generate a type error, and what would fix this?

Comment: Array element types are mainly to allow the implementation to optimize the array storage for a primitive type. If you want to check arbitrary types for safety, you can store the type specifier in the struct and manually check that the new element is of the type in `PUSH-JVECTOR`. CL unfortunately doesn't support generics / type parameters, so there's no compile-time checking for this.

Comment: I was primarily interested in getting an efficient internal representation, rather than run-time safety. But is it correct to say that when you specify optimizations—like (debug 3) vs (debug 0)--the compiler only increases/decreases safety (by including run-time checks)? That is, compiler optimizations do not affect things like array storage or other data representation choices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why there is no type error

The type is checked according to the `array-element-type` of the array:

```
(defparameter w (create-jvector :element-type 'fixnum))

(array-element-type (jvector-vector v))
=> T

(array-element-type (jvector-vector w))
=> FIXNUM
```

Pushing a symbol to `W` leads to an error. As said by jkiiski, the type is used mainly to help the compiler have the opportunity to use specialized representations for arrays (bitvectors, strings, ...).

An `integer` can be a bignum, which is why the upgraded element type is `T`:

```
(upgraded-array-element-type 'integer)
=> T
```

### How to solve your problem

This is the solution hinted by jkiiski, namely add the type to the structure; here I also redefine the constructor directly from the structure:

```
(defstruct (j2vector
             (:constructor make-jvector
                           (element-type
                            &aux
                            (start 0)
                            (vector (make-array 0
                                                :adjustable t
                                                :fill-pointer 0
                                                :element-type element-type)))))
  element-type
  vector
  (start 0 :type (integer 0)))
```

Then you check the type explicitly:

```
(defun push-jvector (elt jvec)
  (assert (typep elt (j2vector-element-type jvec)) ())
  (vector-push-extend elt (j2vector-vector jvec)))
```

Comment: So, it looks like the original create-jvector will work, as long as I specify an element-type that I know can be represented efficiently. The alternate constructor you & jkiiski mention is an interesting abstraction. Might it be used for something like allowing an end-user/programmer to set error constraints on input data?

Answer (score 6):

If you tell `MAKE-ARRAY` an element type, then it will try to allocate a space efficient array. Implementations have some variants typically supported:

Examples:

```
CL-USER 13 > (mapcar #'upgraded-array-element-type
                     '(bit fixnum character))
((UNSIGNED-BYTE 1) (SIGNED-BYTE 64) CHARACTER)
```

But for many types there are no space efficient arrays:

```
CL-USER 14 > (mapcar #'upgraded-array-element-type
                     '(integer string standard-object))
(T T T)
```

You have asked for an integer array and got a general array: see the type `T` returned by `upgraded-array-element-type`.

It's not about type checking, but about asking the runtime to possibly get a space optimized array.

Comment: OK. The only other such types I found (beyond those you mention) are SINGLE-FLOAT, SHORT-FLOAT, DOUBLE-FLOAT, LONG-FLOAT, STANDARD-CHAR, and NIL.

Comment: @davypough: some more. there usually will be variants of unsigned-byte: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32

Comment: @davypough: variants of signed-byte also